# Image editor with High-Pass equivalent

Tags: gimp, image-processing, image-editor

I have license of older version of Adobe Photoshop, I don't really need much, just a few things I use for touching up images. I'm not into amateur digital photography that much anymore and for development environment, I migrated to Linux.

I've been meddling with GIMP, I couldn't quite figure it out yet. For now I'm looking for something equivalent to High-pass, which I used to use in combination with 'Soft light' blending to selectively sharpen images.

Any editor with similar filters available for Ubuntu/Linux?

Comment: Have you tried [High Pass Filter plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/7385) for GIMP?

Comment: Hi @Melebius . I added suggested filter, seems to be doing the job. I notice edge detection is not as good. I followed the instructions, looks like needs more fine tuning. Thanks. Meanwhile alternative suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have Photoshop, you could try running it using Wine (assuming the filters you need are present in said version). And since it's an old version, you're less likely to run into problems.

Visit [the official install page for Ubuntu](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) to get started with the latest versions.

Check the [Wine appdb page for Photoshop](https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?appId=17) to see what results people have got running various Photoshop versions in Wine, and any necessary workarounds.

Comment: I tried this with standalone Wine and Playonlinux, version I have licensed crashes. I can't go beyond first screen to start installation. View error details produces nothing. I'm using v16 with KDE desktop. Changing Wine Windows version didn't help.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but did you try the development version that I've linked above (as opposed to installing from official Ubuntu repositories) ? I'm not sure if Playonlinux uses these versions, so if you still have the patience, you might have better luck with these (currently it's 1.9.19).

Also, do consider telling the GIMP developers on their mailing list if you think something isn't working quite right.